# Problem with installing Go on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: go, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am new to Ubuntu and am trying to install Go onto my server, however I get an error when trying to use Go.

```
Command 'go' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install golang-go  # version 2:1.13~1ubuntu2, or
sudo apt install gccgo-go   # version 2:1.13~1ubuntu2
```

The commands I used to install Go are below.

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.15.10.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ sudo tar -xvf go1.15.10.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ sudo mv go /usr/local
```

Then I appended the following to the bash_aliases file.

```
$ vi ~/.bash_aliases
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Never set GOROOT, and go1.13 is not supported. You can get official precompiled packages from golang.org

Comment: Why not follow the package manager's suggestion?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Because unfortunately Ubuntu's Go packages lack behind, usually 1 or 2 _major_ versions. Always get and install Go from the official home page.

Answer (score 1):

Using APT, there is an official package you can install using Ubuntu

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install golang-go
```

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, you may have to run:

```
sudo apt install golang
```

Hope this helps! Its my first answer!

Comment: Unfortunately Ubuntu's Go packages lack behind, usually 1 or 2 major versions. Always get and install Go from the official home page.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some suggest.

1. check your path var

```
echo $PATH
```

Since you edit ~/.bash_aliases, I think you maybe not source this file.

please try `source ~/.bash_aliases`.

or try

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

beside `~/.bash_aliases` may not be load by default. see if `. ~/.bash_aliases` is in your `~/.bashrc` file.

2. Check if bin can run

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go version
```

if have error, maybe is the package you download is wrong. checksum the tar package(for example: `md5sum xxxx.tar.gz`).

3. check the default path of go

```
which go
```

if go bin not in /usr/local/go/bin/go, you should delete the go bin that shown by `which go`